# Number of anonymous users in a Drupal site?

Tags: drupal-7, anonymous

Is there a way we can know the number of anonymous users in Drupal 7 without the module? I was looking for a query.

Answer (score 0):

A module is the best way such as https://drupal.org/project/google_analytics, otherwise you would need to look at the recent hits reports page and figure it out by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [Visitors](https://www.drupal.org/project/visitors) module is what you're looking for? Refer to its  [community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2432339) for some more details.

Be aware: I'm the maintainer of this module.